# Alternative to Websockets on Hostinger

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I very recently discovered the existence of Websockets (with socket.io), I was super happy with the idea of integrating them into several of my projects, something that I tried to do, but the problem is that my host (Hostinger in shared hosting) does not support Websockets, nor nodejs (as written [here][1] and [here][2]), so unfortunately I had to stop everything ! But now I'm wondering if there is an alternative to do this on Hostinger without doing a setInterval every 5 seconds (Since I'm only developing for fun now and don't want to pay more for the moment).
(I use PHP, JQuery and Javascript mainly on my projects)
Thanks in advance for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: Use better hosting if you need more functionality

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative for WebSockets called **long polling**.

Client sends regular http request, but server does not respond immediately, but waits until there's data to send to the client. When request is ended, client immediately sends new request and waits for data

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is **Pusher**

https://pusher.com/

It lets you build realtime applications
and has a free tier that lets you send 200k messages and handles up to 100 connections at a time